# Standing still to move forward

Tags: propulsion, interstellar-travel, interplanetary, velocity

If our galaxy is tracking through space at ~1.3mm, couldn’t we arrive at point B if we came to a stop at point A.

i.e.  decelerate to -1 g

Answer (score 4):

Of course, but relative to what? For example, consider the rotation of the Earth. At the equator, the ground (with you on it) is moving at 1670 km/hr. You could travel very fast if you "just stopped". But how would you stop? You'd have to somehow start moving 1670 km/hr relative to the earth. That's very very fast. In this case "stopping" relative to the center of the earth is indistinguishable from accelerating relative to the surface.

In the same way, "just stopping" relative to the galaxy is exactly the same as "just going very fast" relative to the Earth & our current velocity.